# SharePoint Online- Errors were found compiling the workflow.The workflow files were saved but cannot run

Tags: designer-workflow

For the past week now we have been experiencing this error when trying to publish new workflows or existing ones

```
Errors were found compiling the workflow.The workflow files were saved but cannot run
```

Anyone facing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and there has been an advisory in the O365 Admin portal for a week now.

```
Title: Unable to edit existing workflows or create new workflows

User Impact: Users are unable to edit workflows or create new workflows in SharePoint 2010 using Designer and other protocols.
```

Comment: ok .Any ETA on this if you know?

Comment: The admin center shows sometime this week.

Answer (score 1):

The SP 2010 are all back online :)